# Mutual Information: How these two equations are equal?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I'm a biologist trying to apply the Mutual Information (MI) to some RNA secondary structure. I know that there exists two MI equation that, mathematically, are equal:

$I(X,Y) = \sum_{x,y} p(x,y) log_{2}\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x) p(y)}$ (1)

$I(X,Y) = H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)$ (2)

And I know that

$H(X) = -\sum_{x}p(x)log_{2}p(x)$ (3)

$H(X,Y) = -\sum_{x} \sum_{y}p(x,y)log_{2}p(x,y)$ (4)

But what I don't know is the process which (1) can be (2) and vice-versa. Can someone, please, teach me?

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One key step is to note that $$\sum_y p(x,y)=p(x)$$ and $$\sum_x p(x,y)=p(y)$$ ([law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)).

Another key step is
$$\log_2 \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)} = \log_2 p(x,y) - \log_2 p(x) - \log_2 p(y).$$

---

The equality then follows immediately:
\begin{align*}
&\phantom{{}={}}H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)\\
&= -\sum_x p(x) \log_2 p(x) - \sum_y p(y) \log_2 p(y) + \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log_2 p(x,y)\\
&= -\sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log_2 p(x) - \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log_2 p(y) + \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log_2 p(x,y)\\
&= \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log_2 \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time. In the second term $-\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x,y)log_{2}p(x,y)$ it should be $-\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x,y)log_{2}p(y)$ ?

Comment: @IvánCastro Yes, just fixed it, sorry about that!