# Why are these two expressions involving probabilities equal?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have encountered an equation I do not understand:

\begin{multline*}
-\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x,y)(\log_{2}p(x)+\log_{2}p(y)-\log_{2}p(x,y))\\
=-\sum_{y}p(y)\log_{2}p(y)+\sum_{x}p(x)\sum_{y}p(y|x)\log_{2}p(y|x)
\end{multline*}

Mainly, I do not understand how we went from ordinary probabilities to conditional ones.

The post [Mutual Information: How these two equations are equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347022/mutual-information-how-these-two-equations-are-equal) is similar, but conditional probability is not used.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove unnecessary information, fix the tags, and clean up the $\LaTeX$. Please take a moment to look at the source to help inform future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle term on the left side is the first term on the right side. (Just note that $\sum_x p(x,y)=p(y)$). 
 In the other two terms on the left just put $p(x,y)=p(y|x)p(x)$ to complete the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the domain of $p$ is finite so that we can ignore any issues relating to switching the orders of summation, 
\begin{multline*}
\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x,y)\left(\lg p(x)+\log p(y)-\lg p(x,y)\right)\\
=\sum_{x}\lg p(x)\sum_{y}p(x,y)+\sum_{y}\lg p(y)\sum_{x}p(x,y)-\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x,y)\lg p(x,y)\\
=\sum_{x}p(x)\lg p(x)+\sum_{y}p(y)\lg p(y)-\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x)p(y\mid x)\lg(p(x)p(y\mid x))\\
=\sum_{x}p(x)\lg p(x)+\sum_{y}p(y)\lg p(y)-\sum_{x}p(x)\sum_{y}p(y\mid x)\left(\lg p(x)+\lg p(y\mid x)\right)\\
=\sum_{x}p(x)\lg p(x)+\sum_{y}p(y)\lg p(y)-\sum_{x}p(x)\lg p(x)-\sum_{x}p(x)\sum_{y}p(y\mid x)\lg p(y\mid x)\\
=\sum_{y}p(y)\lg p(y)-\sum_{x}p(x)\sum_{y}p(y\mid x)\lg p(y\mid x).
\end{multline*}